# jQuery executing JavaScript on dynamically loaded HTML

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have developed a Wordpress site that loads pages dynamically using the `.load` function.

I have installed a few plugins that I NEED to get working, there is no substitute. My problem is that these plugins rely on JavaScript (an AJAX contact form, and a photo gallery) when they are loaded into `div#content` the required JavaScript doesn't execute on the dynamically loaded content.

A normal solution would be load the JavaScript I need with the page, but since this is done with Wordpress and the `<script>` tags are placed in `<head>` by the plugin. Another solution I have considered is using jQuery's `$.getScript`, but again since the JS is already in the head this will cause conflicts. I am really stuck as to where to go next.

Any help appreciated guys.

Comment: Why don't you call your plugin initialization in the "complete" callback of the .load() method ?

Comment: @DidierGhys if you'd posted this as an answer I would have accepted it to give you rep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the "complete" callback of the [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method to instantiate your plugins to the added elements ?

```
 .load( url [, data] [, complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)] )  

 url: A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.    
 data: A map or string that is sent to the server with the request.    
 complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest): A callback function that is executed when the request completes.
```

The use is:

```
$('#insertIntoThis').load('url', function(data, status, xhr) {
    // instantiate here
    // $('#myelement').myPlugin();
});
```